# Casting from (long)double to size_t

Tags: c++, casting, floating-point, type-conversion, precision

I'm trying to implement Sieve of Eratosthenes as efficient as possible. I'd like to set length of my prime array to upper bond of
`pi(n) < 1.25506n / ln n` 
but I'm not sure how to proceed with conversions to do it safely, nor which combination of types is the best for this.

Maximal length of my list would be limited by maximal size of array.

My guess is that ideal combination depends of how size_t is implemented internally and it's upper limit.

I'd like to get result as close to
`ceil( 1.25506n / ln n)` without ever getting smaller number.

Any advises on how to do that?

Comment: What is the size of `n`?

Comment: Please post code and results as text, not images.

Comment: what's `type_t`?

Comment: @NathanOliver how do you suggest posting formulas as text? I'd like to learn how to do this!

Comment: @SergeyA ough, I messed up. size_t

Comment: @SergeyA Well the first could just be written as `pi(n) < 1.25506n / ln n`.  The scond one would be `ceil(1.25506n / ln n)`.  It's not perfect but now people that can't see or have imgur blocked can at least understand what the Q is asking.

Comment: @NathanOliver I followed this anser https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/60020 . How to write formulas as text? E: Oh, OK, I see.

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher n should be as large that result of ceil( 1.25506n / ln n) <= SIZE_MAX, where SIZE_MAX is maximal integer value size_t can represent.

Comment: The maximal size of your array is probably limited by the maximal amount of money you can spend on RAM. On 64-bit platforms `size_t` is going to be 2^64 elements, a huge number indeed, `UINT_MAX` is going to be massive, like 18446744073709551615.

Comment: @tadman OK, but let's reformulate question: I'm want to do conversion from result of floating point operation with real numbers to size_t. I want to get number which is not smaller than actual result. How to do it? Also, is it ok to go with long double or it can produce problems?

Comment: Can you better qualify what you want in terms of actual C++ code? You can cast a `double` to an unsigned int if you want, but you'll lose the decimal component and the upper bound of double is a lot higher than the upper bound of integers.

Comment: Perhaps this is a problem better suited for [Mathematica](http://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/) than C++.

Comment: Provided that your number fit as an precise integer in a double (that 2**53 IIRC?), then use std::lround to get the value you want (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/round)

Comment: You can simply do this with double arithmetic (maybe setting round mode to round upwards). And maybe add one to the result, just to be absolutely safe. I bet that you don't have that much RAM that the precision that double offers is not enough. And even, this upper bound is likely not tight, so it doesn't matter too much, whether you have floating point inaccuracies, or not.

Comment: This question simplifies nicely to "how to find the smallest `size_t` which is greater than or equal to 1.25506 * _n_ / ln _n_ (or detect if no such `size_t` value exists) where _n_ is a `size_t`.

Comment: @tadman thanks, but I'm doing this to refresh my C++ and learn how to solve similar data-type problems (and it is not my first time I'm having this kind of trouble).

@ others - I want it to work for numbers representable with size_t, so I don't worry about overflow. I worry about lost of precision for big doubles and rounding it to wrong (smaller) value, though. So it is THEORETICALLY OK to do it  std::const_cast<size_t>(std::lround(std::ceil( 1.25506n / ln n)+1.0)) ?

Comment: @tadman thanks, but I'm doing this to refresh my C++ and learn how to solve similar data-type problems (and it is not my first time I'm having this kind of trouble).

@ others - I want it to work for numbers representable with size_t, so I don't worry about overflow. I worry about lost of precision for big doubles and rounding it to wrong (smaller) value, though. So it is THEORETICALLY OK to do it  std::const_cast<size_t>(std::lround(std::ceil( 1.25506n / ln n)+1.0)) ?

Comment: The best way to find out if it works for you is to actually execute that code and find out. That's not quite C++ code yet, but it's close.

Comment: @tadman Thank you. I can "get it done" to work on my PC without this question. I want to learn "doing it in the most correct way" and why is it the right way. (after I get it compile-able by changing ln n to log(n) and adding * operators, is it allright?)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to do this:

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <cfloat>
#include <cmath>

std::size_t piUpperBound(std::size_t n) {
    double x = n;
    double num = nextafter(x, DBL_MAX);

    x = log(x);
    double den = nextafter(x, -DBL_MAX);

    double result = num/den;
    result = nextafter(1.25506, DBL_MAX)*nextafter(result, DBL_MAX);
    result = nextafter(result, DBL_MAX);

    return ceil(result);
}
```

This code supposes that `log` has at most 1 ulp error.

The basic idea is to use `nextafter`, which provides us the next possible floating point number. After each operation I call `nextafter`, to modify the number in a way so the resulting expression keeps being an upper bound.

A better bound could be created, if we suppose, that division, multiplication is correctly rounded (true for IEEE-754), and instead of `nextafter`, we could adjust rounding mode (to always round up or down).

Notes:

- Using `ceil` for the original expression may be conservative. For example, if pi(...)=12.2, there are 12 primes number at most, not 13.
- This formula is very conservative, as you can see [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=pi(x),+1.25506*x%2Fln(x)+for+x%3D100000..1000000). So, actually, this whole floating-point business is not required. Even if the code miscalculates a little bit, it will still be an upper bound by a large margin.

Comment: When you write `1.25506`, you don't get 125506/100000. Most C++ compilation platforms give you the `double` closest to the rational, which can be below it. In the same spirit, you may want to write `nextafter(1.25506, DBL_MAX)`.

Comment: @PascalCuoq: fortunately, the closest number is above it :) But you are right, I'll edit my answer, thanks!